# UI program to open .p12 certificates from iOS in ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, deb

I had UI program that I used to open .p12 binary files, but I can't remember what was it. I just remember that I had to install something and it wasn't included in my distro (kubuntu). It was opening the file not for edit, but just preview of the .p12 file. I could read who is the creator , what is the date and to see the keys inside it. My .p12 file is iOS certificate protected with password and when I opened it the program asked for password as well. Please help me to find it because it was very useful. I remember that I had hard time finding it, as I have now.
The file type is PKCS#12 certificate.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://keystore-explorer.org/?

Comment: thank you. This one works (although is not what I had)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ubuntu you can use gcr-viewer (you should open it with a console like `gcr-viewer certificate.p12` as the GUI doesn't have an Open command).

A good program to show, edit and generate certificate is [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/index.html). It's free and Open Source under the GNU GPL.